# Insert all fails blaming duplicates which arent

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, sql-insert

I'm trying to make a query for inserting multiple rows into a table using an insert all in the form:

```
insert all
into application (col1, col2, etc)
values (val1, val2, etc)
select * from application;
```

Wihtout the insert all this works, however when I do it errors with `ORA-00001: unique constraint violated`.  The constraint error code it gives me is for the primary key, but the values I'm trying to insert are not duplicates of the primary key.  Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: `val1`, `val2`, etc. are fixed values you're supplying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're inserting fixed values `val1`, `val2`, etc., they will be inserted once for every row that already exists in your table (since the `into` and `from` both reference `application`). You aren't inserting values that clash with existing primary keys, you're inserting the same *new* primary key multiple times, which generates the same error.

If that table was empty you'd get no rows inserted; if it had one row you'd get one row inserted (probably correctly if you're not manually duplicating the key); otherwise you're automatically creating duplicates. Without the primary key causing the exception you'd double the number of rows in the table every time you ran this.

You can try it on a dummy table with a primary key to see what is actually being inserted:

```
create table t42(col1 number, col2 varchar2(10));

insert into t42 values (1, 'A');
insert into t42 values (2, 'B');
insert into t42 values (3, 'C');

insert all
into t42 (col1, col2) values (4, 'D')
into t42 (col1, col2) values (5, 'E')
select * from t42;

6 rows inserted.

select * from t42;

      COL1 COL2     
---------- ----------
         1 A          
         2 B          
         3 C          
         4 D          
         4 D          
         4 D          
         5 E          
         5 E          
         5 E          

 9 rows selected
```

... so you can see that each `into` clause created one new row for each row that existed in the tablle beforehand. Clearly if there was a PK on `col1` then you'd have inserted duplicates of the new values.

The only time I can think you'd want to refer to the same table is if you're creating rows based on other rows, e.g. (highly contrived):

```
insert all
into application (col1, col2, ...)
values (col1 + 100, col2 || ' adjusted', ...)
select col1, col2 from application;
```

If you want to put in fixed values you can select from dual instead, which will give you a single row per supplied set of values:

```
insert all
into application (col1, col2, ...)
values (val1, val2, ...)
select * from dual;
```

Repeating the demp from above:

```
create table t42(col1 number, col2 varchar2(10));

insert into t42 values (1, 'A');
insert into t42 values (2, 'B');
insert into t42 values (3, 'C');

insert all
into t42 (col1, col2) values (4, 'D')
into t42 (col1, col2) values (5, 'E')
select * from dual;

2 rows inserted.

select * from t42;

      COL1 COL2     
---------- ----------
         1 A          
         2 B          
         3 C          
         4 D          
         5 E          

 5 rows selected
```

Of course there isn't much point using the `insert all` syntax for this unless you have multiple `into` clauses, and even then individual `insert` statements might be clearer.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was the select clause at the bottom. Changing that to dual has fixed it.